# How to Get OSX version during boot time in a daemon programme

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, osx-yosemite

As `Gestalt` is deprecated in 10.10, so I use Apple Script to determine OSX version, the implementation is as follows:

```
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"set os_version to do shell script \"sw_vers -productVersion\""];
```

but this apple script fails during boot time and daemon gets crash. I can't use `NSProcessInfo`
`operatingSystemVersion` as I am using **OSX SDK 10.8** and for now I don't want to upgrade my code to **Xcode 6**. I can't use `operatingSystemVersionString` also because as per Apple Docs - it is not safe for parsing.

Could anyone please tell me how to get OSX version on `10.10` during boot time using **OSX SDK 10.8**.

Could we achieve it through `NSTask`?

Comment: Well you could use the mechanism that `sw_vers` uses and read the property list at `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`, and read the productVersion directly.

Comment: @petesh Will it work boot time also.

Comment: I can't see how it wouldn't. You're just reading a file.

Comment: I used sw_vers -productVersion with NStask and it works well

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says :

```
NewGestalt()    DEPRECATED
```

**Deprecated:
     Use NewGestaltValue instead wherever possible.**

Summary:
     Adds a selector code to those already recognized by Gestalt.

Discussion:
     The NewGestalt function registers a specified selector code with
     the Gestalt Manager so that when the Gestalt function is called
     with that selector code, the specified selector function is
     executed. Before calling NewGestalt, you must define a selector
     function callback. See SelectorFunctionProcPtr for a description
     of how to define your selector function.

Registering with the Gestalt Manager is a way for software such
     as system extensions to make their presence known to potential
     users of their services.

In Mac OS X, the selector and replacement value are on a
     per-context basis. That means they are available only to the
     application or other code that installs them. You cannot use this
     function to make information available to another process.

A Gestalt selector registered with NewGestalt() can not be
     deleted.